# Detect if a user visited page coming from same site

Tags: php

I need to know if a user visited the webpage by clicking on a link from the same website. I can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and check if the domain is the same. But `HTTP_REFERER` is not always set.

I must detect the difference between visiting a page via own website and coming from an external website (or direct visit). This must be able over and over again, meaning that if a user leaves the site and come back through a search result, I again must be able to detect this.

I thought about setting a session, but than I can't detect a second visit within the session lifetime. Also don't see an option for setting a cookie.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Why not using cookies? You can use javascript for detect the clicks on links in your website and set the value in cookies and remove it in the next page

Comment: @MohamedAbdallah, I thought about cookies, but not how your approach! Will try to work that out!

Comment: You can pass a parameter in query string.

Comment: if you need only analytics, implement google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Database(MySQL) to save the `HTTP_REFERER` each time for every visit from a specific `IP` and for a particular date.
You can check the time difference between the two records (like in some minutes) that an IP has accessed and can get the records if a user leaves and come back again to the website. This way you can track the logs for each visitor like how many times a visitor access the website. 
Hope this way you can manage the desired output for your application.

Comment: But like I said, the HTTP_REFERER is not allways set. However I checked and it seems that all major browsers are supporting it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer